# Rsync filter - do I really have to do THIS?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, rsync, file-transfer

Do I REALLY need to write this in filter file to exclude everything and include only `/modules/ims/select/` module?

```
+ /modules
+ /modules/ims
+ /modules/ims/select
+ /modules/ims/select/**
- *
```

from what I understand, rsync applies this filter list on every recursive call. If it can't match anything before `- *`, it will not take that folder into consideration.

That's why

```
+ /modules/ims/select/**
- *
```

by itself does not work, because it can't match that pattern anywhere but the root directory.

Am I missing something or is this the way it's done?

Thanks.

Comment: To non-recursively include only files in `/modules/ims/select` use `rsync {options not including -r} /modules/ims/select/ /path/to/dest` (**note:** the trailing `'/'` following `select/`). To recursively copy everything **under** `../select` use `-r (or -a)` To preform the *recursive* copy, including `../select` itself, use `rsync -r /modules/ims/select /path/above/dest` (**note:** no trailing `'/'` and `above`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I understand but the point is that I have multiple things I want to include, and I want everything else to be excluded. I don't want to call multiple rsyncs, that's why I am using --filter flag with rules specified above.

Comment: You can stack as many `--filter` options together as needed in a single call, e.g. to exclude all `bin` and `obj` directories copying a source tree, you could do `rsync -uai --filter=-_bin/ --filter=-_obj/ source dest`. It just takes deciphering what all filters are needed.